# Laravel redirect with session message does not always persist to my request

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, laravel-5.1

I have an Admin tool built with Laravel where users can perform certain actions on individual records.

The way the code is built I am performing a post to a URL, executing the necessary code, updating the database and then redirecting back with a session message.

Controller Code:

```
return Redirect::back()->with("msg_success", "SMS has been sent!");
```

Now the page that gets rendered from the redirect has a check at the top to display the session message if it exists.

View Code:

```
@if (Session::has('msg_success'))
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
        <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <strong>Success! </strong>{{ Session::get('msg_success') }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

For some reason, sometimes the message is displayed and other times it is not. I cant for the life of me figure out why. Could it be middle ware that is intercepting the request and then performing another request and it is getting destroyed? I do not see anything in there that looks like it would cause this.

Any ideas would help. I thought about using a URL parameter when redirecting like

```
return Redirect::to('explicitURL?success=whateverthesuccesmessageis')
```

But I would prefer not do this as my action is shared among different URL's.

Comment: why wouldn't you turn that into its own array? `->with(["msg_success" => "SMS has been sent!"]);`

Comment: Hmm wasn't sure what the difference was between that what I have? I guess if I wanted to pass more than just a success_msg I could see the benefit.

Comment: You aren't sending any data to the view otherwise.

Comment: Pretty sure I am, I have done it this way it works. But I am having an issue where the message shows some times and not others.. leading to me think there might be something going on with my session or middleware intercepting my request.

Answer (score 3):

In your **controller** add this:

```
Session::flash('msg_success', 'SMS has been sent!')
return Redirect::back();
```

And in the **View**:

```
@if (Session::has('msg_success'))
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in">
        <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <strong>Success! </strong>{{ Session::get('msg_success') }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```

Comment: Interesting, after reading their docs this looks like the correct way to do it. Il give it a shot and see if the issue still occurs. Thanks.

Comment: after further reading it looks like this is doing the same thing that I am currently doing.... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data .. if you scroll towards the very bottom.

Comment: You are not setting a session in your controller. If you need to access a Session variable, you need to create it first.

Comment: Or try this: `return redirect('sms-page')->with('msg_success', 'SMS has been sent!');`